# FunctionClauseError when calling :wxFrame.new from Elixir

Tags: elixir, wxwidgets

I have just two questions :)

1. What's wrong?
2. How do I understand what's wrong without asking on Stackoverflow?

Elixir code:

```elixir
import WxConstants
...
wx = :wx.new
frame = :wxFrame.new(wx, wxID_ANY, "Game of Life", size: {500, 500})
```

Output:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :wxFrame.new/4
    gen/wxFrame.erl:111: :wxFrame.new({:wx_ref, 0, :wx, []}, -1, "Game of Life", [size: {500, 500}])
```

WxConstants module: https://github.com/ElixirWin/wxElixir

Comment: Try single quotes around `Game of Life` instead of double.

Comment: Wow didn't think anyone even knew that github repo was there except me.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Google does his job ;) Thanks for the module.

Comment: @raacer I can see that I probably need to add some sample code to that module.  I hope it helps regardless. :)

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Yes, it would be great to see some sample code. Anyhow I've found some similar example on Github, and I'm trying to make it working now.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I've added some constants while working on my project (it works finally, thank you!). You can get the changes back from here https://github.com/artemrizhov/lang_comparison/blob/master/wxconst.ex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dogbert had already answered the first question, I would answer the second one.

> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in ...

is one of the most frequently happening errors in Elixir, as well as any other language supporting pattern matching in function clauses. Consider this contrived example:

```
defmodule M do
  def test(param) when is_binary(param), do: "binary"
  def test(param) when is_list(param), do: "list"
end
M.test("Hello, world")
#⇒ "binary"
M.test([1, 2, 3])
#⇒ "list"
```

When there is no function clause, that could be matched against the parameters given, the error above happens:

```
M.test(42)
#⇒ ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in M.test/1
```

That said, the library, you are using, expected other type(s) of one or many parameters. Let’s check: [`:wxFrame.new/4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/wxFrame.html#new-4) expects:

```
Parent = wxWindow:wxWindow()
Id = integer()
Title = unicode:chardata()
Option = {pos, {X::integer(), Y::integer()}} | 
         {size, {W::integer(), H::integer()}} | 
         {style, integer()}
```

The third parameter is expected to be `unicode:chardata()` which is in turn Erlang charlist, that is denoted in Elixir by single quotes. Hence the comment by @Dogbert: use single quotes around '`Game of Life'`.

Comment: But `unicode:chardata()` does allow `binary()`, so it looks like a bug in the documentation: http://erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#type-chardata.

Comment: @Dogbert indeed; in any case [`new/4` has `is_chardata` guard](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/wx/src/gen/wxFrame.erl#L112) and tries to explicitly convert list into binary two lines below.